# jQuery.easing.js compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-easing

At [this site](http://open-pages.com/Alpinemadotcom/), the menu and slide banner do not work together.

Below before `</body>` there are two scripts for each menu and banner and they use same or different jQuery version.

If  I use *either* or *both* versions. the menu do not work properly or the banner do not work with clicks and no fade in outs or slides (abrupt image change).

What can be wrong?

**--------Update--------**

I found, after quite hit and tries, that `jquery.easing.js` is causing problems for banner and if excluded, the menu doesn't work. `jquery.easing.compatibility.js` doesn't solve problems either. I suspect `jquery.min.js` (v1.3.2) is also causing problems.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you please explain your question more accurately?

Comment: This is not the place for "go look at my site and fix it" type questions.  You are expected to compose and post a concise example of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You cannot seriously expect to use version 1.3 of jQuery with newer plugins.  Too much has been changed leading up to version 1.8.

Comment: @Mooseman I stated Below before </body> there are two scripts for each menu and banner and they use same or different jQuery version. ---- thats whats the problem is

Comment: Yes, the problem is that they use two different versions. **You cannot use two versions of jQuery on one page**, only use one, as you can see in my answer. Easing should be able to be fixed, see my answer.

Comment: @Mooseman I am now using one jquery. but easing, which is not fixed

Comment: 1) Change `fx: "backout",` (Line 197) to `fx: "easeOutBack",` and use both  `jquery.easing.js` and `jquery.easing.compatability.js`.

Comment: @Mooseman did that. doesnt works.

Comment: But still use the `jquery.min.js`, v1.3

Comment: @Mooseman with 1.3 the menu dont work and the banner gets smooth in fads but resizes randomy. I think I am best up with an new banner? (as I need this menu specifically) you know of any free ones? or is there a solution with current script?

Comment: If jQuery v1.3 causes the menu to fail, then stick with v1.8. I have used [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) and [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html) in the past with no problems. They do both require some CSS to be written, though.

Comment: How about [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/)? If you would like to ask me a few more questions, we can move this to chat on here. EDIT: I forgot that you need 20 reputation to chat.

Comment: @Mooseman ya. thats why skype comes in. and super. its using jquery 1.7 i guess. the menu only uses 1.3 despite. i hope for good. just needed a fade in and out thing. not the slide thing.. thanks again!

Comment: i think there would be a fade tag in it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ for documentation. `jquery.easing.compatability.js` uses the old easing names. If the menu uses the new names (`jquery.easing.js`), then that is a problem. The menu script should allow you to change the transition name to the old equivalent, then you would only use `jquery.easing.js`.
  `jQuery.min.js` is not a problem. However, because jQuery 1.3 is significantly older than the 1.8, it may include deprecated attribute(s) used by the slider. Try using only v3.2, or find a new slider plugin.